# What are the video players available for elementary OS?

Tags: video-player

What are the video players available for elementary OS and how to install them?

I would like to know installation from the Software center and using terminal command:

1.SMplayer [here](https://elementaryos.stackexchange.com/questions/2405/what-are-the-video-players-available-for-elementary-os/2409#2409)

2.VLC [here](https://elementaryos.stackexchange.com/questions/2405/what-are-the-video-players-available-for-elementary-os/2408#2408)

3.Banshee [here](https://elementaryos.stackexchange.com/questions/2405/what-are-the-video-players-available-for-elementary-os/2696#2696)

4.mpv [here](https://elementaryos.stackexchange.com/a/2834/2708)

Comment: This is _really_ broad, but these kinds of things tend to be useful, so I'll leave it to the community.

Answer (score 9):

### Audience (Videos)

elementary OS comes with its own video player preinstalled. It's called [Audience](https://launchpad.net/audience), but it's commonly referred to as Videos in the elementary community. It offers a minimalistic user interface, it works with a large variety of video codecs' and it manages subtitles just fine.

[image: Audience running in elementary OS Freya]

Comment: nice screenshot =)

Answer (score 6):

### VLC

[VLC](http://www.videolan.org/vlc/) is probably the most popular open source video player. It can handle a stunning amount of files (it's not limited to just videos), it can be run on a large variety of platforms (Linux, Windows, OS X, Unix...) and it's highly customizable.

You can install it by typing `sudo apt-get install vlc` inside of your terminal or by searching for it using Software Center.

[image]

Answer (score 3):

**[SMPlayer](http://smplayer.sourceforge.net/)**:

SMPlayer is a free media player for Linux with **built-in codecs** that can play virtually all video and audio formats.

It doesn't need any external codecs. Just install SMPlayer and you'll be able to play all formats without the hassle to find and install codec packs.SMPlayer is a free media player.

**Installation**:

Install from **software center** (easy way)

**Or**

From terminal:

```
sudo apt-get install smplayer
```

---

[image: Imgur]

Possible to display two subtitles

For screenshots refer [here](http://smplayer.sourceforge.net/en/screenshots)

---

Comment: 965292qqq\2\....555555555555555.\\521\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\5\.5699999995555.............58596

Comment: @elmato what? ^

Comment: Bloody cat... ;p

Answer (score 1):

**Banshee**

[Banshee](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Banshee_(media_player)) is an open-source media player.

It is available in elementary OS (freya) **Software Center**.

You can install by using the command in terminal:

`sudo apt-get install banshee`

[image: Imgur]

Answer (score 1):

**MPV Player**

MPV Player is a free, open source, and cross-platform media player. It is based on MPlayer and mplayer2. It supports a wide variety of video file formats, audio and video codecs, and subtitle types.

```
sudo apt-get install mplayer2
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:mc3man/mpv-tests
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install mpv
```

[image]

While mpv has no official GUI, it has a small controller that is triggered by mouse movement. mpv leverages the FFmpeg hwaccel APIs to support VDPAU, VAAPI, DXVA2, VDA and VideoToolbox video decode acceleration.

Comment: your screenshot is attractive +1 =)

Comment: Can I suggest you- [edit] answer and post only about the particular video player, for example [here](https://elementaryos.stackexchange.com/a/2696/2708),

Comment: @Ravan sure i'll edit the answer. thank you for letting me know.